# Prove that a linear surjective map is an isometric submersion between normed vector spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, normed-spaces

If I am not wrong to prove that a linear surjective map $\pi:(V_1,||.||_1)\to (V_2,||.||_2)$ is an isometric submersion between the normed vector spaces is equivalent proving that $\pi$ projects the closed unit ball to the closed unit ball. Why they are equivalent?

P.S. $\pi$ is said to be an isometric submersion if $\forall w\in V_2, ||w||_2=inf \{||v||_1: \pi(v)=w\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prove first that $\pi$ is an isometric submersion iff $\pi$ projects the **open** unit ball in $V_1$ to the **open** unit ball in $V_2$.

Suppose that $\pi$ projects the open unit ball to the open unit ball. We need to prove that for arbitrary $w\in V_2$ $$||w||_2=\inf\{||v||_1:\pi(v)=w\}.$$ If $w=0$, this is trivial. The assumption implies that $||\pi||\leq1$ (operator norm). Therefore, for each $v\in V_1$ with $w=\pi(v)$ we have $$||w||_2\leq ||\pi||\cdot ||v||_1\leq ||v||_1.$$ Consequently, $$||w||_2\leq\inf\{||v||_1:\pi(v)=w\}.$$ If $||w||_2=1$, $(1-\epsilon)w$ is in the open unit ball for each $\epsilon>0$, so $(1-\epsilon)w=\pi(v_\epsilon)$ for a suitable $v_\epsilon$ in the open unit ball of $V_1$, i.e. $||v_\epsilon||_1<1$. In other words, $w=\pi\left(\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}v_\epsilon\right)$. Hence, $$\inf\{||v||_1:\pi(v)=w\}\leq ||\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}v_\epsilon||_1<\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}.$$ Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we conclude $$\inf\{||v||_1:\pi(v)=w\}\leq 1=||w||_2,$$ so that the claim is proven for $||w||_2=1$. Let now $w\in V_2$ be arbitrary, as long as $w\neq 0$. Then $\frac{1}{||w||_2}w$ is  a unit vector and, by what I have just shown, $$||\frac{1}{||w||_2}w||_2=\inf\{||v||_1:\pi(v)=\frac{1}{||w||_2}w\}.$$ Multiplying both sides by $||w||_2$ and noting that $\pi(v)=\frac{1}{||w||_2}w$ iff $\pi(||w||_2\cdot v)=w$ as well as $||||w||_2\cdot v||_1=||w||_2\cdot ||v||_1$, we have obtained the desired conclusion.

Suppose now, conversely, that $$||w||_2=\inf\{||v||_1:\pi(v)=w\}$$ and let $w$ be an element of the open unit ball in $V_2$. Then, there exists a $v\in V_1$ with $||v||<1$ and $\pi(v)=w$, so that the open unit ball in $V_2$ is contained in the image of the corresponding ball in $V_1$. On the other hand, for each $\tilde{v}\in V_1$ the assumption implies (set $w=\pi(\tilde{v})$) $$||\pi(\tilde{v})||_2=\inf\{||v||_1:\pi(v)=\pi(\tilde{v})\}\leq ||\tilde{v}||_1.$$ This shows the converse set inclusion, in other words that $\pi$ does indeed project the open unit ball to the open unit ball.

Finally, under the additional assumption that $V_1$ (and therefore $V_2$ since $\pi$ is surjective) is finite dimensional, I show the desired equivalence involving the **closed** unit balls. I accomplish this by showing that the conditions for the open and the closed balls are equivalent. Let $U_i$ and $C_i$ denote the open and closed unit balls in $V_i$, respectively. Firstly, $\pi(U_1)\subseteq U_2$ is clearly equivalent to $\pi(C_1)\subseteq C_2$, since both are equivalent to $||\pi||\leq 1$. If $\pi(C_1)\supseteq C_2$, then $\pi(U_1)\supseteq U_2$: for $y\in U_2$, there exists a $\rho>1$ with $\rho\cdot y\in U_2\subseteq C_2$, eq $\rho=\frac{2}{1+||y||}$. By assumption, $\rho\cdot y=\pi(x)$, $x\in C_1$. Hence, $y=\pi(\frac{1}{\rho}x)\in\pi(U_1)$. Conversely, suppose that $\pi(U_1)\supseteq U_2$. We have $$C_2\subseteq \rho U_2\subseteq\pi(\rho U_1)$$ for each $\rho>1$. Choose $y\in C_2$. For each $\rho\in(1,2]$, there exists $x_\rho\in\rho U_1$ with $y=\pi(x_\rho)$ - in other words, $||x_\rho||<\rho$. Consider the sequence $(x_{1+1/n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Since $2C_1$ is compact, there is a convergent subsequence $$(x_{1+1/n(k)})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\to x.$$ By continuity of $\pi$, we have $\pi(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\pi(x_{1+1/n(k)})=y$. Additionally, $||x||=\lim_{k\to\infty}\underbrace{||x_{1+1/n(k)}||}_{<1+1/n(k)}\leq 1$, so $x\in C_1$. We conclude $y=\pi(x)\in\pi(C_1)$.

---

**Note1:** Originally, the question was asked differently, namely dropping the word "submersion" from the claim. For completeness' sake, here is my original answer:

Your claim is not correct: let $V_1=\mathbb{C}^2$ and $V_2=\mathbb{C}$, both normed by the appropriate Euclidean norms. Then the projection to the first component, $$(x,y)\mapsto x,$$ is surjective and maps the closed unit ball in $V_1$ to the one in $V_2$, but isn't isometric, since it isn't even one-to-one. I'm not certain right now, but perhaps if you require that $\pi$ is bijective, your claim could be correct.

**Note2:** It appears as though I never use the surjectivity of $\pi$. In fact, it is used to ensure the welldefinedness of $\inf\{||v||_1:\pi(v)=w\}$.

**Note3:** The fact that $V_1$ is finite dimensional is only used to show the implication $\pi(U_1)\supseteq U_2\Rightarrow\pi(C_1)\supseteq C_2$. The rest, especially the equivalence of "$\pi$ is an isometric submersion" and $\pi(U_1)=U_2$, is valid in the general case, too.

Comment: yes you are completely right. I should edit my question and ask is it is ai isometric submersion or not.

Comment: @Majid how do you define an isometric submersion? I was unfamiliar with the term; a quick google search revealed as the only definition the condition you wish to be equivalent to it...

Comment: I will add it to the question then.

Comment: @Majid I have updated my answer.

Comment: Your solution for this case sounds right. In fact I like it. Now let's see what is behind being closed!

Comment: @Majid Thanks! I have come up with three quarters of it: If $U_i$ denotes the open unit ball in $V_i$ and $C_i$ the closed one, then $\pi(U_1)\subseteq U_2$ is clearly equivalent to $\pi(C_1)\subseteq C_2$, since both are equivalent to $||\pi||\leq 1$. Conversely, $\pi(C_1)\supseteq C_2$ implies the corresponding inclusion for the open balls: for $y\in U_2$, there exists $\rho>1$ with $\rho\cdot y\in U_2\subseteq C_2$, eg $\rho=\frac{2}{1+||y||}$. By assumption, $\rho\cdot y=\pi(x)$, $x\in C_1$. Hence, $y=\pi(\frac{1}{\rho}\cdot x)\in\pi(U_1)$. [Tobecontinued.]

Comment: @Majid [sequel to my last comment] it remains to be proven that the inclusion for the open balls implies the one for the closed balls. This is the part I haven't been able to show. In fact, I have some doubts about it, since it would require $\pi(C_1)$ to be closed, which I feel to be wrong in general, I haven't come up with a counter example, though. If I don't get an idea until tomorrow or someone answers on this question, I'll start one myself...

Comment: Yes and I think the point is one you have that $\pi$ projects the open unit ball on the open unit ball, using continuity one can prove that it maps the closed unit ball to the closed unit ball.

Comment: @Majid Indeed, but I just couldn't pull it off...certainly, $C_2$ is a subset of $\pi(\rho\cdot U_1)$ for each $\rho>1$. If the corresponding preimages would converge (or at least a subsequence) as $\rho\to 1$, we would be done, by continuity. If $\pi$ is assumed to be one-to-one, this is true in a trivial manner, since the preimages are all the same. If $V_1$ is finite dimensional, we get the convergence of a subsequence by compactness of the closed ball with radius 2, say (consider only $\rho\in (1,2)$). But how about the general case?

Comment: This case is indeed for the finite dimensional cases.

Comment: @Majid Unfortunately, I don't understand your last comment...do you mean you are only interested in finite dimensional spaces?

Comment: yeah, actually, I am working with finite dimensional case.

Comment: @Majid oh, alright then. I'll include the argument for closed balls in my answer tomorrow, so that we can wrap up and you can accept the answer!

Comment: @Majid I have updated my answer.